# Chrome developer console offers 'background-color' property instead of general property 'background'

Tags: css, background, google-chrome-devtools, background-color

while using google developer console in chrome in styles section it offers me immediately "as I type" background-color property. Few months ago it has been offering general property "background" which I prefer more.

Is there any chance to customize these hints or there is nothing I can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, There is no problem in Chrome developer console. You just need to type `background` and then colon `:` . it will set `background: #color` .
Give it a try.